# Paths in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a rectangular grid.

I want a short and elegant way of generating a straight path from `[x0,y0]` to `[x1,y1]`, where either `x0=x1` or `y0 = y1`.

For example, on input `[1,3], [3,3]` the output `[[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]` should be generated. Likewise if the input is `[3,3], [1,3]`.

I have tried `[[i,j] for i in range(self.origin[0],self.end[0]+1) for j in range(self.origin[1], self.end[1]+1)]`, but it only works for the case where the input is ordered.

Comment: Make life easy on yourself and break up the problem, there is no reason to iterate over both x and y when only one is changing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question states that the solution from `x -> y` should be the same as the solution `y -> x`, i.e. we're only interested in defining the points on the path, not in any ordering of those points. If that's true, then simply find out which path has the smaller `x` (or `y`) and designate that as the origin.

```
origin = (3,3)
dest = (1,3)

origin, dest = sorted([origin, dest])

path = {(i,j) for i in range(origin[0], dest[0]+1) for j in range(origin[1], dest[1]+1)}
# note that this is now a set comprehension, since it doesn't make any sense
# to use a list of unique hashable items whose order is irrelevant
```

of course, this solves any obstructionless 2-D pathfinding. If you know that only one direction is changing, then only look in that direction.

```
origin, dest = sorted((origin, dest))
if origin[0] == dest[0]:  # y is changing
    path = {(origin[0], j) for j in range(origin[1], dest[1]+1)}
else:  # x is changing
    path = {(i, origin[1]) for i in range(origin[0], dest[0]+1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the **step** argument to your range, deriving the sign of the start & end difference:

```
x_dir = copysign(1, self.end[0] - self.origin[0])
... for i in range(self.origin[0], self.end[0]+1, x_dir) ...
```

Do likewise for the y direction.

Comment: I was hoping for something less verbose

Comment: how do you get less verbose than this?

Comment: Maybe it is impossible, but I would not be surprised if there was a one liner using maybe a function from the std

Comment: @Jsevillamol certainly you could do this as a one-liner, but it would be MORE verbose not less. `[(i, j) for i in range(self.origin[0], self.end[0]+1, math.copysign(1, self.end[0] - self.origin[0])) for j in range(self.origin[1], self.end[1]+1, math.copysigh(1, self.end[1] - self.origin[1]))]`

Comment: That depends on your metric of *verbose*.  You could certainly first determine which variable is changing, and then deal only with the other.  See @AdamSmith's answer for a lexically simple switch of order.  It may execute a tad slower, but readability would dictate what you want to use.

Comment: Also I just noticed I typo'd `copysigh` in my ugly-as-sin one-liner. That's strangely fitting.